# Twitter bootstrap: Dropdownlist and Textbox doesn't align properly

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with a dropdownlist, and two text boxes for my users to select their birthdays. All three of them are in a table cell, and they have the same height value. However, for the life of me I can't figure out why they dropdown seems to be floating like 2px next to the text boxes. Below is my code and a picture.

```
 <tr>
            <td class="tdLeft" style="padding: 10px; text-align: right">Birthdate:</td>
            <td class="tdRight" style="text-align: left">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" CssClass="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Month" runat="server" Width="136px" style="display: inline; text-align: center" Height="45px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="01">January</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="02">February</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="03">March</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="04">April</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="05">May</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="06">June</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="07">July</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="08">August</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="09">September</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="10">October</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="11">November</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="12">December</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbMem1Day"
                    CssClass="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Day"
                    runat="server" Width="74px" style="display: inline"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbMem1Year"
                    CssClass="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Year"
                    runat="server" Width="124px" style="display: inline"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: You really shouldn't be using tables for layout any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class "form-inline" to your form.

```
<form class="form-inline">
```

If you can't do it that way, you can always use JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").addClass("form-inline");
});
</script>
```